# Customize column mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm a beginner in hibernate, and I wonder if there is a way to map from one type in the database to another one to the `@Column` annotation in the class. In my specific example, there is a duration which is saved in the database as a BIGINT representing the number of seconds and I would like to map it to `java.time.Duration` in my entity object. I'm working in a Spring project.

The table (I'm creating it with flyway and I'm not using hibernate automatic table creation):

```sql
CREATE TABLE times (
  id       BIGINT      PRIMARY KEY     AUTO_INCREMENT,
  duration BIGINT
);
```

The Entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table("times")
class TimeEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column("duration")
  private Duration duration;
  // - when reading from DB I would like to assign:
  // :: Duration.ofSeconds(<duration bigint from database>)
  // - when writing to DB I would like to write:
  // :: duration.toSeconds(); -> long
}
```

Is it possible to achieve it with hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic) , there is a `DurationType` which maps `BIGINT` to `java.time.Duration`. So you don't need any custom mapping, declaring a `Duration` field type should be enough.

If you are using an old version of Hibernate, you may need to add `hibernate-java8` as a project dependency.

**Caveat:** the default convertor transforms the sql type to/from nanos, so you may need a helper method, or override `DurationType` to transform to/from seconds.